# Problema con ajax, error 403 (Forbidden) al procesar consultas

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un textarea al que le escribo una consulta como: `SELECT* FROM usuarios` para procesarlas en un documento php y poder extraer el resultado de dicha consulta.

Va todo bien en este aspecto, pero siempre que uso cláusulas, tales como: LIMIT o WHERE me manda un error 403 (Forbidden) indicando la ruta de mi archivo .php en donde proceso la consulta.

¿Por qué pasa esto? Estuve leyendo acerca de ello con problemas similares pero ninguno me ayudó. Tengo mi hosting en Godaddy y la información la proceso con JQuery y Ajax. Valoraré mucho cualquier ayuda al respecto. Gracias.

HTML

```
    <form>
       <label>Consulta</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Consulta SQL"></textarea>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" id="ejecutar-consulta" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Ejecutar</button>
```

JQuery

```
var dataContent;
(function() {
    $('textarea').focus();
    $('body').on('click','#ejecutar-consulta', function() {
        $('#ejecutar-consulta').hide();
        $('textarea').removeAttr('style');
        $('.response-sql').html('<i style="font-size:17px;" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Ejecutando consulta...');
        var consulta = $('textarea').val().trim();
        if ( consulta.length > 0 ) {
            $.post('includes/herramientas/generador-reportes/controller.php',{key:'ejecutar-consulta',sql:consulta}, function(dataResponse) {
                dataContent = dataResponse;
            }).complete(function() {
                console.log(dataContent);
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error al procesar la solicitud.');
        }
    });
})();
```

PHP

```
    $sql = $_POST['sql'];

    $DoQuery = $db->sql($sql);

    $GetColumns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery);

    $headersTable = array_keys($GetColumns);

    while ( $f_informacion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery) ) :
        $contentOne = array();
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($headersTable); $i++ ) :
            $contentOne[] = utf8_encode($f_informacion[$headersTable[$i]]);             
        endfor;
        $contenidoSQL[] = $contentOne;
    endwhile;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A. El error 403**

El error 403 Forbidden (Prohibido), que estás recibiendo, indica que el servidor web cree que el flujo de datos HTTP enviado por el cliente era correcto, pero el acceso al recurso identificado por la URL está prohibido por alguna razón.

Es posible que tu archivo php o la carpeta donde se encuentra tengan restricciones de acceso indicadas en el archivo .htaccess o en otra parte.

**B. Pero hay otra cosa mucho más grave: tu código es totalmente vulnerable a ataques SQL (SQL injection)**

**Jamás envíes consultas directas a tu base de datos, pero jamás.**

Si tú permites enviar esto a la base de datos desde un input box o text area:

`SELECT * FROM usuarios`

y un usuario mal intencionado escribe esto:

`SELECT * FROM usuarios;` **`DELETE FROM tutabla;`** **`DELETE FROM tuotratabla`**

envías sin ningún tipo de control dos o más consultas a tu BD que se ejecutarían... sólo que la segunda y la tercera (en este caso) borrarían todos los datos de cualquier tabla que se indique en el DELETE.

O, más grave, un usuario mal intencionado podría obtener mediante consulta, las claves de accesso, o modificarlas.

Por favor, lee esto sobre [Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

**Solución a (B):**

Usar siempre [consultas preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php) y para la conexión a la BD usar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) o [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Gracias, @A. Cedano Valoro tus sugerencias, voy a echarles un vistazo y a aplicarlas. Después de hace tiempo, retomo yo esta cuenta donde la compartía con algunos compañeros para hacer preguntas. De igual forma, gracias, saludos.

Comment: Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya servido @FernandoTorres. He borrado los comentarios anteriores para limpiar la respuesta. Saludos.